# Which one is correct between "chain of email" and "chain of emails"?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

What is the correct usage between "a chain of email" and "a chain of emails"? Why?

By "a chain of email" I mean an email thread where many people have chimed in from time to time and that has grown very large over time.

Comment: You aren't referring to a [chain email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_letter#Email), are you?

Comment: You haven't made it clear what you're asking here. What are you trying to describe, when you say "a chain of email(s)"? A single email that gets forwarded from person to person to person? A long dialog between two emailers? A series of spam messages that gets sent to multiple recipients? If you explain what  you are trying to describe, this question can be reopened.

Comment: @J.R I have made it clear what I meant by a chain of email which is essentially an email thread where many people are involved and have participated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would call this an ***email thread***, rather than a *chain of email*. You can read more about email threads [here](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/1503/email-thread), [here](http://cellphones.about.com/od/phoneglossary/a/email-thread.htm), and [here](http://blog.millnet.co.uk/index.php/faq/what-is-an-email-thread/), and see if that would be a good term. As one of those websites says:

> An email thread is an email message and a running list of all of the subsequent replies pertaining to the original email.

Getting back to your question, **mail** can be considered a mass noun (much like *sand*, *rice*, and *money*), meaning that it can be tricky figuring out when and when not to pluralize the word.

If, for some reason, you didn't want to use *email thread*, I would call it a *chain of email* if it was one message that got forwarded many times. To me, *emails* connotes several distinct messages from several different sources, not one message that got appended with several subsequent replies.

Comment: _Email thread_ is what I would use too, since I don't think that in English _chain_ gives a sense of "something very long" as in "a long thread of emails."

Answer (score 1):

Just as you would say "a pearl necklace" but "a necklace of pearls", so also you would say "an email chain" but "a chain of emails".

Answer (score 0):

Email **thread**, email **chain** and email **stream** can all mean the same thing: a collection of email messages including the original and all subsequent replies and forwards from the original sender, recipients and anyone else who was copied or blind copied.

Such a collection of messages usually maintains the same Subject, but this is not a requirement. Although not recommended, it is usually possible to change the Subject before replying or forwarding.

Please note, the email **thread**/**chain**/**stream** is a collection of the actual messages - not simply a list of the messages.

Comment: Please be careful when answering a question. This answer does not explain the "correct usage", as was requested by OP.